Is encrypting the access token before sending it to the frontend and decrypting it on the backend a secure approach?
I'm a new developer and curious about security best practices. If, before sending an access token to the frontend, it is encrypted on the backend and then stored in localStorage, and later decrypted on the backend when an API request is made, will this approach still leave the application vulnerable to attacks? What are the potential security concerns with this method, and is there a better way to handle tokens securely?
Ive been sending accesstoken from backend server and storing it in the localstorage on browser, now whenever I tried sending HTTP request to backend server, i just pass on the accesstoken for authentication of user. Its not a safe approach but still works for small projects. But thinking of production level code, its venerable to attacks like CSRF and XSS ,etc. But what if we follow the above approach and try doing same, will the application still be vulnerable. If YES!
Whats correct solution to do this.

Is the token already tamperproof, e.g. signed? Then encryption is not necessary. Are the contents of the token secret and must not be seen by the user? Then encryption is necessary.

"it is encrypted on the backend." Using what key? If it's a key only the server knows, then really the "encrypted token" is just the token; anyone who has the encrypted token can just use it, so the encryption doesn't matter. If it's shared key, than the client can read the key, so it's not really encryption. What attack are you envisioning that your approach will prevent? (When you say "HTTP" I will assume you mean HTTPS. That encryption is absolutely necessary. If you're using unencrypted HTTP, yes, then encrypting the token could be useful, but really you should just use HTTPS.)
